# Undefined post variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#register button[name=btnPosta]").click(function() { 
    console.log('clicked'); 

    thisBtn = $(this); 
    parent = $(this).parent(); 

    name = parent.data('name');

    $(this).attr('disabled', true); 

    $.post('register.php', {
      name: (name)
    }, function(data) {
      console.log('Ajax success'); 

    $('#message').html(data); 
      thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset
    });

    console.log('Ajax success'); 
  });
}); 
});
```

This is my JavaScript function that sends the value of name (inputed from a input box) however undefined is displayed instead of what was inputeed into the input box.

```
<div class = "Interactlogin" id = "register"> 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Username: <td>
      <td> <input type = "text"  class = "field" name = "name"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Password: <td>
      <td> <input type = "password" class = "field" name = "password"> </td>
    </tr>
      <td > Email: <td>
      <td> <input type = "email" class = "field" name = "email"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  <td>
      <td><button  class='regular' id = "btnPost" name = 'btnPosta'> Log In  </button <td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id = "message">
</div>
```

This is the HTML markup where input is located.

Comment: change this line name = parent.data('name'); to var name1 = parent.data('name'); and give this variable in $.post as parameter.

Comment: Why not `<input id="username"` and `,{ name : $("#username").val() }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
name = parent.data('name');
```

Use:

```
name = $('#register').find('input[name="name"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to use $.data rather than $.val which you probably meant.

Use

```
name = $('#register input[name="name"]').val();
```

rather than

```
name = parent.data('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#register :button[name=btnPosta]').click(function() { 
    console.log('clicked'); 


    var name = $('#register :input[name = "name"]').val(); 


    $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
    $.post('register.php', 
            name: name, 
            function(data) { 
                 console.log('Ajax success'); 
                 $('#message').html(data); 
                 $(this).attr('disabled', false); 
           });
```